# need to write 2.5 million data into csv from resultset, what is the best approach to write these huge data in java

Tags: java

Need to write  2.5 million data into csv from resultset, what is the best approach to write these huge data in java.Currently its taking 1.5 hours to write.
Sample Code:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("test.csv"), "UTF-8")), false);

int colcount= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

while(rs.next()){
  // working on some headers
   for (int i= 1; i<= colcount; i++) {
        Object value = rs.getObject(i);
        pw.println(value.toString());
   }
}
```

please help me

Comment: He does, through the "new FileOutputStream("test.csv"), "UTF-8")" statement. I don't understand why this question is so negatively noted. Of course, there's some formatting issues to achieve a csv file in the proper format, and it might be no way to do the conversion faster with Java, but the opener of the post has not asked a stupid question.

Comment: Pearphs he should write to out variable instead, ok. And pw we don't see it defined. Whatever, matt, you see the underlying question that is about performance. If his code wouldn't been able to write anything he would have started by telling us that. But, BTW, I see no way to go faster than he does, except using a dedicated API. (Jackson may have some classes helping doing csv conversions ?)

Comment: @UmamahiG I wanted to suggest disabling `autoFlush`, but I saw you already did that. I am not sure if you can go any faster, 2.5 million rows is a lot of data. Also the bottleneck might be reading from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try to prepare CSV directly in database query (if it is possible). I mean, instead of running query like `select * from table` and process each column in response, execute `select id || ', ' || name from table` and use first column as whole CSV line.

Comment: Thanks Bor Laze for reply, your idea but need to have file generation in java as i need to add some other data